# Get a debian directory out of a source package

Tags: debian, structure, packagemaker

I'm trying to decompile a source package because I want to look at the preist en prerm files. Those files are normally in the debian folder but when I extract the source package I don't find any debian folder. Is there a simple command or other way to get the debian folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean "preinst and prerm" files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to it from the source for package foo:

```
apt-get source foo
```

which will get the `.orig.tar.gz`, the `.dsc` with control information and the `.diff.gz` with Debian changes (if any) and the `debian/` directory added to the source for the build. It will have `(pre|post)(inst|rm)` files too.

From the `.deb` binary, you can use `ar` and `tar` as per the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

try `ar x [dpkg-package]` (where dpkg-package is the binary-package) which generates a `control.tar.gz` which contains the `postinst` (and other) files.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually simple: The debian subdirectory is only there in the source for dpkg, i.e. it is a meta-directory used by dpkg, and dpkg will look at it and build the final .deb, where there is only a textfile "debian-binary", a "data.tar.gz" and a "control.tar.gz".

To get the initial "debian" directory, you would have to look at the upstream source control, or ask the maintainer/s of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apt-get source packagename
```

this will download the file and decompress it, along with debian specific files.